# How to setup Static Ip in Fedora 19

Tags: networking, fedora, static-ip-address

While using Fedora 19 on VMware player(Harvard CS50x appliance 19) , the guest OS is not able to access the internet even though the host is .

How to set static Ip address to access Internet ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First find out your interface using `ifconfig`

Edit the config file for that interface
using your favorite text editor:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 //where eth1 is your interface
```

You will need to change BOOTPROTO from dhcp to static and add IPADDR, NETMASK, BROADCAST and NETWORK variables.

```
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.8.248
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.168.8.255
NETWORK=192.168.8.0
GATEWAY=192.168.8.1
TYPE=Ethernet
PEERDNS=no
```

Save the file    `:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`

Also add your DNS servers

```
vi /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver your_Router_ip
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google's DNS Server
```

You are ready to browse!